# Remove meaningless words from corpus in R

Tags: r, tm

I am using `tm` and `wordcloud` for performing some basic text mining in R. The text being processed contains many words which are meaningless like asfdg,aawptkr and i need to filter such words. 
The closest solution i have found is using `library(qdapDictionaries)` and building a custom function to check validity of words.

```
library(qdapDictionaries)
is.word  <- function(x) x %in% GradyAugmented

# example
> is.word("aapg")
[1] FALSE
```

The rest of text mining used is :

```
curDir <- "E:/folder1/"  # folder1 contains a.txt, b.txt
myCorpus <- VCorpus(DirSource(curDir))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removePunctuation)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeNumbers)

myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus,foo) # foo clears meaningless words from corpus
```

The issue is `is.word()` works fine for handling dataframes but how to use it for **corpus** handling ?

Thanks

Comment: hello check `content_transformer` it's what you need

Comment: @s.brunel, `content_transformer` works with function that modify corpus, `is.word` is just returning True / False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it will be the most resource efficient method (I don't know the package very well) but it should work:

```
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus )
all_tokens       <- findFreqTerms(tdm, 1)
tokens_to_remove <- setdiff(all_tokens,GradyAugmented)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(removeWords), 
                 tokens_to_remove)
```

Comment: Thanks @Moody for response, it filters out words to some extent.

Comment: To some extent ? Maybe make sure both sides are lowercase

Comment: Yeah thanks, i applied some transformations before these steps, works all fine. Only issue it is resource consuming.

Answer (score 6):

If you are willing to try a different text mining package, then this will work:

```
library(readtext)
library(quanteda)
myCorpus <- corpus(readtext("E:/folder1/*.txt"))

# tokenize the corpus
myTokens <- tokens(myCorpus, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE)
# keep only the tokens found in an English dictionary
myTokens <- tokens_select(myTokens, names(data_int_syllables))
```

From there you can form at document-term matrix (called a "dfm" in quanteda) for analysis, and it will only contain the features found as English-language terms as matched in the dictionary (which contains about 130,000 words).

Comment: Thanks @Ken for help, i looked up the `quanteda` and reduced some data rather than considering all words for speeding the process